# Is there a regular expression to return a match of a repetition of the same characters?

Tags: .net, regex

Using .NET regular expressions.

Let's say I have the following text:

> ddddddddddd

And I would like to test for a repetition of more than 2 for any character.

The regex should not return a match for a text containing double letters like the word *"look"*.

---

### UPDATE

Do not assume the input text only consists of repetition of the letter d.
I want ANY repetition of characters.

Comment: All by themselves? Within words? Should "dddddeeeee" match? Should "tyyypo" match? Please provide example inputs and expected results.

Comment: well, words are not relevant here so your examples would match.

Comment: Well, how should anyone know that "words are not relevant here", if you don't say so?

Comment: I fail to see where such a repetition would occur outside of words ? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
(.)\1{2,}
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v4lg)

The `.` matches any character, this character is stored in group 1, because of the brackets around it. The `\1{2,}` checks then for 2 or more of this character (together with the originally matched character then 3 or more.)